# How to wire multiple 9 V batteries together in parallel using Schottky diodes?

Tags: batteries, diodes, schottky

I need help figuring out what kind of Schottky diode to use to make sure my batteries don't blow up. They are 9 V batteries. I want to wire like 9 of them together to make a long-lasting battery. Is this possible?

Comment: any one. And 9V batteries are unlikely to blow up even if short-circuited. They just don't have that much power in them.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Wouldn't a 6-cell AA battery holder be easier to get 9 V with a higher capacity? Cheaper batteries too.

Comment: Schottky diodes have leakage. And most current is drawn from highest voltage battery until all are discharged to same voltage. 9V batteries don't have much energy anyway. It might be better to consider some other battery. What is the load and expected current draw and lifetime you want from the battery?

Comment: I have seen 9V primary cell lithium batteries, but I don't know much about them.  They might be of concern as far as mistreated batteries blowing up.  I'd avoid them for this even with Schottkys.

Comment: what type of batteries are they?

Comment: I am trying to wire a cell phone to a charger to a battery pack made of my own fashion. I do not know the load TracFone My Flip 2 4G LTE is what im trying to power its just a flip phone.

Comment: Energizer Max Alkaline 9 Volt is the battery

Comment: If you measure how much current from the battery is used, and how long you want it to work for, perhaps someone can suggest a single battery that meets your needs. Does it have to be 9 volts?

Comment: it does not have to be 9 volt and i want to it last 9 days or so.

Comment: The phone takes a 9 volt charger if that helps.

Comment: a 9  V block battery consists of six AAAA cells ... it would make more sense to use six C or D cells

Comment: using the battery between C and D cells that lasts longer should I use schottky diodes ?

Comment: _"The phone takes a 9 volt charger if that helps."_ - no, it doesn't help. How do you know that it needs 9 volts?